# Redirection is not working with mod_rewrite in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect few URIs having query string like:

`/pages/foo.bar?pageId=123456` to `http://some.site/spam/egg/`

`/pages/foo.bar?pageId=45678`  to `http://another.site/spaming/egging/`

I have this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pages/foo.bar$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageId=123456$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://some.site/spam/egg/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pages/foo.bar$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageId=45678$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://another.site/spaming/egging/ [R=301,L]
```

But its not working, showing 404. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @anubhava yes..i have many Apache internal "Redirect 301 source dest"  patterns on the top..

Comment: @anubhava note that those rules are working properly....also i have a `RewriteEngine` snippet at the very top..all of these are working properly..only the queries are not redirecting..

Comment: As I said move these 2 rules before all other rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you very much....its working...this chunk was the culprit `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]` ....could you please explain this? also please add an answer so that i can accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move these 2 rules i.e. before all other rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line as other rules might be overriding this.

(Based on your comments) Your culprit rule is this rule:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Which is actually rewriting every request to `index.php` and changing value of `REQUEST_URI` variable to `/index.php` thus causing this condition to fail:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pages/foo.bar$
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example, you get redirected to

```
http://some.site/spam/egg/?pageId=123456
http://another.site/spaming/egging/?pageId=45678
```

You can use your browser developer tools to see the redirection (in the Network tab).

Maybe the query strings in the redirected URL lead to a 404? You can add a `?` at the end of your redirection to clear the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pages/foo.bar$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageId=45678$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://another.site/spaming/egging/? [R=301,L]
```